# php regex get custom url and string inside href tag

Tags: php, regex

I get content of page like this :

```
$html = file_get_contents('example.ir');
```

Now I want get href tags inside **$html** where have to be **custom url + string** ;

for example i have three href :

```
1- href="http://example.ir/salam/ali/...."  => http://example.ir/ + salam/ali/....
2- href="http://example.ir/?id=123/..."     => http://example.ir/ + ?id=123/...
3- href="?kambiz=khare/..."                 => ?kambiz=khare/...
```

I want number 1 and 2 because have **http://example.ir + some string**.

Resault have to be like these :

```
1- http://example.ir/salam/ali/....
2- http://example.ir/?id=123/...
```

Help me plz :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Description

This regex will capture the anchor tags providing they have an href attribute whose value starts with `http://example.ir/`. It will then capture the entire href value into capture group 1.

```
<a\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref="(http:\/\/example\.ir\/[^"]*))  # get the href attribute
(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"\s]*)*"\s?> # get the entire  tag
.*?<\/a>
```

[image]

## Example

**Sample Text**

Note the last line has a potentially difficult edge case.

```
<a href="http://example.ir/salam/ali/....">salam ali</a>
<a class="Fonzie" href="http://example.ir/?id=123/...">plus id 123</a>
<a class="Fonzie" href="?kambiz=khare/...">not an http</a>
<a onmouseover=' href="http://example.ir/salam/ali/...." ; funHrefRotater(href) ; " href="?kambiz=khare/...">again not the line we are looking for</a>
```

**Code**

This PHP example is to only show that how the match works.

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/<a\b(?=\s) # capture the open tag
(?=(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"][^\s>]*)*?\shref="(http:\/\/example\.ir\/[^"]*)) # get the href attribute
(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?> # get the entire tag
.*?<\/a>/imx',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = <a href="http://example.ir/salam/ali/....">salam ali</a>
[0][1] = http://example.ir/salam/ali/....
[1][0] = <a class="Fonzie" href="http://example.ir/?id=123/...">plus id 123</a>
[1][1] = http://example.ir/?id=123/...
```

Comment: I Love you man :)
Nice And Great Description
you solved my problem :*****